# How to only keep the data I want after retrieving data from mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, tkinter

```
mydoc = mycollection_Users.find_one( {}, { "Username": 0})
```

this is the code I wrote to get the password from MongoDB, when I put 0 in the search value it will give me all the values except Usernames' value.
but I get the value like this

```
{'_id': ObjectId('618bc65e33c87d5cfbdd5a28'), 'Password': 'example'}
```

how can I only keep what the actual password is and remove everything else, the product should be just "example" and nothing else

Any help will be great, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert the value into string and slice the text to get the password or put it in a variable and write `password['Password']`

Comment: I'm sorry, i couldn't exactly get what ur saying

Comment: 1 . Convert this ```{'_id': ObjectId('618bc65e33c87d5cfbdd5a28'), 'Password': 'example'}``` into string and you can get the password by substring 2. you can simply put it in a variable and write ```some_variable['Password']```

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
mydoc = mycollection_Users.find_one( {}, { "Username": 0, '_id': 0}).get('Password')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove the id value by adding "'_id': 0"
so the code now is

```
mydoc = mycollection_Users.find_one( {}, { "Username": 0, '_id': 0})
```

but I still want to remove the {'password': }

Answer (score 0):

convert the value into string and slice the text to get the password or put it in a variable and write password['Password']